# Building dataframe from nested MongoDb

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, dataframe

This is the structure of my MongoDB:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"), 
    "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2016-11-23T12:21:10.726+0000"), 
    "data" : {
        "price" : [
            {
                "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-11-23T23:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "value" : 32.92
            }, 
            {
                "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-11-24T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "value" : 31.54
            }, 
            {
                "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-11-24T01:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "value" : 29.14
            }, 

    },
    "Type": "f"
    "runTime" : ISODate("2016-11-24T15:26:00.000+0000")
}
```

I have 2 different type of documents, one with `Type: f` and the other with `Type: r`. I wanted to grab allof the documents that have *type f* and add the `price` data which includes `timeStamp` and `value`, ** as well as saving the `runTime`. I have several run times, which include similar information, `timeStamp` for the same time, with more than likely a different `price`.

This is what I have so far and am able to build a dataframe with the price and timestamps, however, I'm not sure how to include the `runTime` in the dataframe as well.

```
query_fc = {'Type': 'f', 'runTime': {"$lte": model_dt_till}}

df_f = pd.DataFrame(self._collection.find_one(query_fc, sort=[('createdDateTime', -1)])['data']['price'])
```

also `model_dt_till` is just an estimate of a time that happened right after `runTime` for the query use. 'self' referring to the db

Comment: Why don't you save the result from `find_one` to a variable, and access this variable `['data']['price']` and `['data']['runTime']`? Then join the dicts and to `pd.DataFrame(data=joined_dicts)` Then do `df.ffill()` in runtime column to fill NaNs with same runtime value

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried implementing your recommendation, but I seemed to mess up when I joined the dicts. I then tried saving the `runTime` to a variable. `run_model = self._collection.find_one(query_fc, sort=[('createdDateTime', -1)])['runTime']` and then adding it to the dataframe that I had made `df_f['forecastModelRun'] = run_model`